# Simple AJAX POST return HTML

Tags: php, jquery

I am using $.post to post some data into the server and if that php file works then I am returned with some html snippet. Now the problem lies within the $.post code. I can't insert the returned data from the php file onto the original file that contains the $.post code. Firebug shows that the html snippet does return back but I'm seeing it on my screen. What's the problem?

Here is the code below for the file containing the .post()

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

$.post('ajax_send_band_request.php', {

user_id : user_id,
band_request: band_request,
where_to_go: where_to_go,
when_start: when_start,
when_end: when_end,
time: time  

}, function(data){

$(data).find('#message_return').appendTo("#response_from_request_verification")

})  

});

</script>           

<div id="response_from_request_verification"></div>
```

Here is the summarized php file version.

```
if(this_function_sends the data to the server($register_data) === true);

{

?>

<div id="message_return">Request sent!!</div>

<?php

} else

{

?>  

<div id="message_return">Request was not sent!</div>    

<?php   

}

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `.find()` part, you already have the `div#message_return` with $(data). [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) doesn't check the root element for a match, just descendants.

```
$(data).appendTo("#response_from_request_verification")
```

Comment: actually this might be a valid point, assuming of course the summaried php does infact show the top/end of the document and there's not other headers etc going in.

Comment: oh cool, response while I was writing. Don't you hate that? :)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see wrong here is the missing ; on the appendTo line.

Make sure you have that on your actual code, and then all I can suggest is running through it with an interactive debugger like firebug.

Set a breakpoint on the appendTo line, use the console to make sure $(data).find('#message_return') is getting the peice you want etc

Answer (score 0):

try this :
$('response_from_request_verification').html(data);
or
$('response_from_request_verification').appendTo(data);

Comment: Also this would replace the content of the response div, rather than append to it